# Pandas pivot table memory error, lots of memory available

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Info about my df:

```
RangeIndex: 14151145 entries, 0 to 14151144
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id    object
idf   object
ch    object
hr    uint8
dtypes: object(3), uint8(1)
memory usage: 337.4+ MB
```

My system has 120GB memory and when I run:

```
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns=['idf','ch'],aggfunc='count')
```

My resultant pivot table will have 10800 columns.

My memory consumption goes to around 35 GB, and then I get a memory error.
I can't understand this issue as I have a lot of free memory.

I am running the code in JupyterNotebook.

Comment: One idea - how working `groupby + unstack` alterantive ? `dfp = df.groupby(['id', 'idf','ch']).count().unstack([1,2])` ?

Comment: Originally tried the same thing, gave me memory error at unstack operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything which would help me process all of my data in one go.

So, sliced my df into **n** pieces w.r.t to **ids**, each id can have multiple samples.

```
def partition(lst, n):
    division = len(lst) / float(n)
    return [ lst[int(round(division * i)): int(round(division * (i + 
    1)))] for i in range(n) ]

chunks_df = pd.DataFrame()

ids = dt_m['id'].unique()
part_ids=partition(ids,5)

i=0
gc.collect()
for lst in part_ids:
     chunks_df=chunks_df.append(dt_m[dt_m['id'].isin(lst)].PIVOT_OPERATION())

     print("{} batch done".format(i))
     i=i+1
```